# How do you scroll in a UIScrollView in the Playground?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

Can you actually scroll in a UIScrollView in a Playground? In the example bellow, I want to be able to scroll down and see the label.

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let contentView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200))
contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 120, 20, 20))
label.text = "a"

contentView.addSubview(label)

let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
scrollView.flashScrollIndicators()

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = scrollView
```

Comment: It works by clicking and dragging - only since Xcode 7.3 beta 7D129n +, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: 7.3 was released to the App Store on 3/21/2016. It's best to download it [there](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12).**

As Eric says, interactivity with playgrounds was added in Xcode 7.3 beta 3. You can read the full announcement [here](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=35). Since Xcode 7.3 is still in beta, you'll need to download it from [here](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/).